# MySQL: What kind of index should I create in this table?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Suppose this is the SQL code of the table:

```
CREATE  TABLE `user_is_in` (
  `id_user` INT NULL ,
  `id_city` INT NULL ,
  `when` DATETIME NULL ,
  INDEX `fk_user` (`id_user` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_city` (`id_city` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_user` )
    REFERENCES `user` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_city`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_city` )
    REFERENCES `city` (`id` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The use of the table is to store kind of Foursquare checkins (A user was registered on one place at one time).

Now I have 2 options:

- Create an unique index with the 3 fields and no primary key:

  UNIQUE INDEX `id_user_is_in_UNIQUE` (`id_user` ASC, `id_city` ASC, `when` ASC)
- Create an additional classic id autoincrement field

I don't like the 2nd option because I want to create queries over users and cities (i.e.: search all users who made a checkin in a city on one date)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this table is going to be used as a foreign key in any other tables, you'd be better off with the auto_increment int field. Otherwise you'll have to do drag around the user/city/when fields in every foreign table, which gets to be a serious pain very quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted some advices on which kind of indexes create. And Marc, this table has 2 fk, but no other tables have foreign keys to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do both. Add an auto-incrementing primary key and add a uniqueness constraint against all three columns. With a separate system assigned keys you make it easier to define foreign keys to this new table, if and when eventually required. And having the uniqueness constraint against all three columns will ensure that duplicate data is not created.

Some quick side notes:

- Since this is an association table, your columns really should be
  `NOT NULL`.
- You probably want to CASCADE delete's of a city down to the
  association table.

Comment: Ok, I think you're right. Only one little change: I prefer 'on delete restrict', to prevent accidental deletions. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, on delete restrict is also a good option to go with. Good luck with the rest of the program!